# Unable to change Materialize's Date Picker's previousMonth & nextMonth

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

So far all other properties of the i18n object seem to work and change as described in the documentation except for the previousMonth and nextMonth. No matter what I try they remain the same default icons. I would appreciate any help that guides on how to customize these.

Below is a a simple html page that reflects the issue (note the rest of the i18n options have been removed as they are reflected correctly):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection"
    />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Date Picker Customization</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
          <form action="#">
            <div>
              <input type="text" class="datepicker" />
              <label for="date">select a date</label>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT CODE SECTION -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      var options = {
        format: "dd mmm, yyyy",
        yearRange: 2,
        showMonthAfterYear: true,
        i18n: {
          previousMonth: "P",
          nextMonth: "N"
        }
      };
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".datepicker");
        var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);
      });
    </script>
    <!-- END CODE SECTION -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at all. Argh :/